# in xCode/Swift, modify string "turn on Bluetooth to Allow [app] to Connect to Accessories"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, bluetooth, ibeacon

My app requires BLE (bluetooth low energy) to detect proximity of users' phones to one another (therefore it does not use "accessories").  I want to modify the string that is displayed when the user does not have bluetooth enabled on their iPhone (mentioned in the title).

I have tried using the .plist key "Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description" but this does not work.  Have also scoured the internet.  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be a documented string in Apple's defined keys:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

An alternative may be to detect if Bluetooth is on or off before trying to use it, then present your own dialog first, explaining to the user why the app needs the permission even though it isn't really connecting to accessories.  Then, only once the dialog is dismissed, trigger the event that will prompt the user.